# Route constraints with pipe delimited values only picking up first value in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am curious as to why this route is not working:

```
routes.MapRoute("Tracking",
                                    "{mailingId}/{subject}/{listItemId}/MailReport.{fileExtension}",
                                    new { controller = "Mailing", action = "OpenerImage", subject = UrlParameter.Optional },
                                    new
                                    {
                                        mailingId = new NonEmptyGuidRouteConstraint(),
                                        listItemId = new NonEmptyGuidRouteConstraint(),
                                        fileExtension = @"(aspx|php|asp|html|htm|json|xml)"
                                    });
```

the `fileExtensions` parameters is only picking up the first parameter in the list so if I got to a page with ..../MailReport.php  I get a 404 error.

UPDATE:

I think this is more of an IIS issue than a routing issue. I think IIS is trying to interpret the extension before the routing engine does. Just a thought, because I also tried creating a custom Route Constraint and it will only work for ASPX extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) rules to handle this. Without writing my own routing classes (which may or may not work) or handlers, I do not think this is possible

**Update:**

After some further research, adding this to the web.config allowed me to bypass IIS's routing:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
    </modules>
```

This goes in the `system.webServer` section and I believe you must be running in integrated mode or this section is ignored.